# Как читать такой массив?

Tags: массивы, javascript

Всем привет, я не спец, так что не судите строго. Итак, имеется такая функция:

```
function ImageUploader(id) {
this.id = id;
images_uploaders.push(this);}
```

Далее на страничке идет ее вызов таким образом:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    new ImageUploader('Id'); </script>
```

где Id -  это уникальное число.

Моя задача прочитать массив этих чисел. Подскажите, как это правильно сделать? Пробовал вот так, но ничего не получилось((

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
images_uploaders[images_uploaders.length - 1].onComplete = function () {
    var SummDok = document.getElementById('Summ');
    for( var i = 0; i<images_uploaders.length ) {
        SummSumm = SummSumm + images_uploaders[i];
            }
    SummDok.innerHTML = SummSumm;
}
</script>

<div id="Summ"></div>
```

Comment: асинхронные же поди операции, надо не так делать, надо опцию oncomplete добавить в конструктор объекта и при создании указывать callback или ещё как нить перебирать, например в цикле делать запуск инициализации объекта.

Answer (score 1):

Вам же нужен массив id этого объекта? То есть надо писать

```
SummSumm = SummSumm + images_uploaders[i].id;
```

плюс опечатка в

```
for( var i = 0; i<images_uploaders.length ) {
```

пропущен инкремент i++

Comment: Спасибо, за подсказки, действительно ошибок наделал(

однако вот так исправил и все равно не работает:

<script type="text/javascript">
images_uploaders[images_uploaders.length - 1].onComplete = function () {
 var SummDok = document.getElementById('Summ');
 for( var i = 0; i<images_uploaders.length; i++ ) {
  SummSumm = SummSumm + images_uploaders[i].id;
            }
 SummDok.innerHTML = SummSumm;
}
</script>

Comment: Для теста попробовал так:

<script type="text/javascript">
images_uploaders[images_uploaders.length - 1].onComplete = function () {
 var SummDok = document.getElementById('Summ');
 SummSumm = 'test';
 SummDok.innerHTML = SummSumm;
}
</script>

и слово 'test' отображается, т.е. проблема видимо опять таки в том, что скрипт не правильно обращается к данным из массива.

Как думаете в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Без полного кода наверное не разберемся. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ZqCsE/ посмотрите - здесь new ImageUploader(10); new ImageUploader(11); в сумме дают 21. 
Вы пользуетесь firebug или другой панелью для отладки js?

Comment: ну у вас вообще объект кривоват  слегка. конструктор меняющий глобальную переменную, это как-то крутовато